# Google Sheets Changelog onEdit() script does not return data but only repeats heading

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, changelog

I'm very new to scripts and trying to get the best out of and onEdit() function to track changes made on a collaborative spreadsheet.

The script seems to run well given that a line is added to the Changelog sheet every time a change is made by any user at all on the sheet.
However, it only sometimes registers the data i'm seeking, and most of the times registers a line which is a copy of the heading: [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1AAt.png)

Do I have something wrong with authorizations here? Or is it something else?

Thank you so, so much!

--

Here is the detail of the script:

```
    function onEdit(e) { 

    var changelogSheetName = "Changelog";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    var timestamp = new Date();
     var currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var currentSheetName = currentSheet.getName();
    var previousValue = e.oldValue;
    var newValue = cell.getValue(); 
    var typeChange = "Edit";
    if (currentSheetName == changelogSheetName) return;
    var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
    if (changelogSheet == null) {changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());}
    changelogSheet.getRange('A1:G1').setBackground('#E0E0E0');  
    changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Sheet", "Cell", "Type", "Old Value", "New Value", "User"]);  
    changelogSheet.deleteColumns(8,19);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
    changelogSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 170);
    changelogSheet.setColumnWidth(7, 170);
    changelogSheet.protect();
    var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    if (previousValue == null){typeChange = "Add";} else if (newValue == "") {typeChange = "Remove";}
    changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, currentSheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), typeChange, previousValue, newValue, user]);

    }
```

Comment: About `However, it only sometimes registers the data i'm seeking, and most of the times registers a line which is a copy of the heading` and `Do I have something wrong with authorizations here? Or is it something else?`, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code should be inside your `if (changelogSheet == null)` statement since you only want this part to be executed if the sheet **ChangeLog** does not exist. This also causes the script to write headers every time an event occurs.

```
changelogSheet.getRange('A1:G1').setBackground('#E0E0E0');  
changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Sheet", "Cell", "Type", "Old Value", "New Value", "User"]);  
changelogSheet.deleteColumns(8,19);
changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
changelogSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 170);
changelogSheet.setColumnWidth(7, 170);
changelogSheet.protect();
```

Here I edited your code, fixed some logic and utilize to use of event object(e):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedSheet = ss.getSheetName();
  var changelogSheetName = "Changelog";
  if (editedSheet == changelogSheetName) return;

  var changelogSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
  if (!changelogSheet) {
    changelogSheet = e.source.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, e.source.getNumSheets());
    changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Sheet", "Cell", "Type", "Old Value", "New Value", "User"]);
    changelogSheet.getRange('A1:G1').setBackground('#E0E0E0');
    changelogSheet.deleteColumns(8, 19);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
    changelogSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 170);
    changelogSheet.setColumnWidth(7, 170);
    changelogSheet.protect();
  }
  
  var timestamp = new Date();  
  var previousValue = e.oldValue;
  var newValue = e.value;
  var typeChange = "Edit";
  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation();

  var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  if (previousValue == null) {
    typeChange = "Add";
  } else if (newValue == "") {
    typeChange = "Remove";
  }
  changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, editedSheet, cell, typeChange, previousValue, newValue, user]);
}
```

**Edited Sheet:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thank you so, so much @Nikko!! It works perfectly!!